# UI Designed in Photoshop for Software

Tags: java, python, user-interface, photoshop

so I am actually trying to get into software development and I currently have just spent a few days making a GUI in Photoshop. Now I know how to code in Java and Python but I have never implemented a GUI before. I am stuck on this because I know I can write the code and everything but how do I take what I made in Photoshop add some java or python code to it to make certain things happen? I have zero experience in this and I have only written code to accomplish tasks without the need for a GUI.

Comment: There are PSD to HTML converters out there, but I have never used any and have no idea how well they work. That could be a solution if you are working on web-design project.

Comment: I wish this was a web-design project because I have experience with that. I need to make a software that will run continuously on a display.

Comment: I don't know of any methods to automatically convert from Photoshop documents to Java or Python code. You might have to manually re-create each element by-hand in code. For Java just search for "Swing basics".

Comment: Also, possible duplicate: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895607/turn-photoshop-design-into-java-gui?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

> but how do I take what I made in Photoshop add some java or python code to it to make certain things happen

No, you cannot expect things to happen magically, for that you need to learn front-end technologies like HTML, CSS, JavaScript etc and manually convert the UI which is in Photoshop to corresponding code. This applies for web applications.

If you want to build desktop application, you need to use Swings, SWT etc to achieve the same.

> I have zero experience in this

If this is the case, I recommend to read some basic tutorials, then you will get idea what to do

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to transfer your UI design into GUI in program.

It's similar to web design: everything in Photoshop is design or resource, it's not useful and accessible unless you transfer them into html/css/javascript. Design in Photoshop could provide you element should be what size, what color and where to put, also what you see (like picture resource), but you need to write html code for visiting in web.

I am not familiar with Java GUI, maybe Swing is an option. For python, you could try [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) or [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro%27) for GUI.